# How to define predicate in prolog programming?

Tags: prolog

> Define the following predicate into a prolog program so that `Min` is the smaller of two numbers `X` and `Y`.

```
min (X, Y, Min)
```

Can you help me understand the question?

Comment: To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already.

Comment: The question is asking you to write a Prolog predicate, `min(X, Y, Min)` which succeeds if `Min` is the minimum of the values `X` and `Y` (as stated in the question, *`Min` is the smaller of the two numbers `X` and `Y`*).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In Prolog, we talk about *predicates*. In other languages you would probably call it a function, but in mathematics we are firm that a function associates a single value with the result of applying some formula to some other parameters to the function. That directionality does not hold in Prolog, so we call it a predicate or a relation.

The canonical solution to this problem is just this:

```
min(X, Y, Min) :- X =< Y, Min = X; Min = Y.
```

In Prolog, you always have a Horn clause, which has a head and a body. The head is what goes before the `:-` and names the predicate. The body is the list of expressions to the right of the `:-`. You should read this as "infer `min(X, Y, Min)` when `X =< Y` and `Min = X`, or else `Min = Y`". If the body of the clause is fulfilled, the head of the clause is inferred. In other words, if `X =< Y` and `Min = X`, then you could say `min(X, Y, X)` holds.

This says, essentially, if X =< Y, then Min is X; otherwise, Min is Y. It is probably more readably expressed with multiple *clauses*:

```
min(X, Y, X) :- X =< Y.
min(X, Y, Y) :- X > Y.
```

But this will create an unnecessary *choice point*; Prolog may think it has multiple solutions here even though you and I both know that X can only either be greater-or-equal to Y *or* less than Y. (We might inform Prolog of our awareness by using the *cut* operator, !, but it's overkill for this situation when you could just use conjunction and disjunction.)

Answer (score 2):

This returns the min arguments of X&Y

```
min(X,Y,M):-
X<Y,!,M=X.
min(X,Y,M):-
M=Y.
```

Comment: You have a singleton variable on your second clause, and I am vaguely concerned that the code is not entirely backwards-correct as a result.

Comment: Just saw your answer it's totally more elegant and has no singletons. I am at my learning phase of prolog I don't get what you mean by backwards-correct, I just debugged it and it works fine.
[trace] 15 ?- min(1,5,M).
   Call: (7) min(1, 5, _G6208) ? creep
   Call: (8) 1<5 ? creep
   Exit: (8) 1<5 ? creep
   Call: (8) _G6208=1 ? creep
   Exit: (8) 1=1 ? creep
   Exit: (7) min(1, 5, 1) ? creep
M = 1.

Comment: It does appear to work, but I'm suspicious because the clause by itself is equivalent to `min(X,Y,Y)` with no guard. Relying on the cut in another clause to supply correctness makes me shudder. Presumably @false can demonstrate a way to trip over backwards correctness; this is an area where I can now smell the problem but still can't reliably produce the effect of it. Essentially what it means is that if you hit something later in the query that causes you to reconsider a choice point, you could be backed into a clause unexpectedly.

Comment: So adding the conditions to the bottom question would work? Like min(X,Y,M):- Y<X, !, M=Y. That way the compiler could work through the predicate both ways and not evade checks.